# Java versions are inconsistent in jenkins running in Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build my simple spring boot application which uses Java 17 through Jenkins job. Jenkins is running in a docker container. App building fails on Jenkins with the following error.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project login-service: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]`

AFAIU the reason for this is Jenkins job is not able to find Java 17 which is required by the application.

By default `Temurin-11.0.18+10` was installed on Jenkins but I have installed and configured Java 17 on my Jenkins container. However, the app still fails with the above-mentioned error.

The version seems to be configured okay when I check the Java version in the docker container.

[image]

I have also configured another Jenkins job to check the Java version and strangely the java version I get from the Jenkins job is Java 11.

Here is the script of the job that tests Java version on Jenkins.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test Java') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    env | grep -e PATH -e JAVA_HOME
                    which java
                    java -version
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it gives the following output

```
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10, mixed mode)
```

[image]

But as you can see in the first image when I run the same commands in the docker container (which I run in the Jenkins job to check the Java version) it gives me Java 17.

Any hints where I am making a mistake in configuring Java?

Comment: From memory, I think Jenkins has it's own JVM which it will use if you don't provide another for the job. I think you need to register the Java 17 JVM which is also in the container and configure the Jenkins job to use that registered JVM.